# epoll loops on disconnection of a client

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, server-side, epoll

I am trying to implement a socket server by using `epoll`. I have 2 threads doing 2 tasks:

1. listening to incoming connection
2. writing on screen the data the client is sending.

For my test I have the client and the server on the same machine with 3 or 4 clients running.
The server works fine until I don't kill one of the client by issuing a `CTRL-C`: as soon I do that the server starts looping and printing at a very fast rate data from other client. The strange thing is that

1. the client sends data each 2 seconds but the rate of the server is higher
2. `epoll_wait` is also supposed to print something when one of the client disconnects as it is checking also for EPOLLHUP or EPOLLERR
3. `epoll_wait` should wait a bit before printing since I gave him a timeout of 3000 milliseconds.

Can you help? Could it be that I am passing in a wrong way the epoll descriptor to the other thread? I cannot understand since the code looks similar to many examples around.

Thanks a lot

Mn

```
 // server.cpp
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <cstring>
 extern "C" {
 #include <sys/epoll.h>    
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <netdb.h>
 #include <pthread.h>
 }

 #define MAX_BACKLOG 10

 void* readerthread(void* args){
     int epfd = *((int*)args);
     epoll_event outwait[10];
     while(true){
         int retpw = epoll_wait( epfd, outwait,20, 3000 );
         if( retpw == -1 ){
         printf("epoll error %m\n");
         }else if( retpw == 0 ){
         printf("nothing is ready yet\n");
         continue;
         }else{
             for( int i=0;i<retpw;i++){
                 if( outwait[i].events & EPOLLIN ){
                     int fd = outwait[i].data.fd;   
                     char buf[64];
                     if( -1 == read(fd,buf,64) ){
                         printf("error reading %m\n");
                     }
                     printf("%s\n",buf);
                 }else{
                     std::cout << "other event" << std::endl;
                 }                  
             }
         }
     }  
 }

 int main(){ 

      int epfd = epoll_create(10);
      if( -1 == epfd ){
      std::cerr << "error creating EPOLL server" << std::endl;
      return -1;
      }

      pthread_t reader;
      int rt = pthread_create( &reader, NULL, readerthread, (void*)&epfd );
      if( -1 == rt ){
      printf("thread creation %m\n");
      return -1;
      }



      struct addrinfo addr;
      memset(&addr,0,sizeof(addrinfo));
      addr.ai_family   = AF_INET;
      addr.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
      addr.ai_protocol = 0;
      addr.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;

      struct addrinfo * rp,* result;
      getaddrinfo( "localhost","59000",&addr,&result );
      for( rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next ){

      // we want to take the first ( it could be IP_V4 
      // or IP_V6 )
      break;
      }     

      int sd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
      if(-1==sd ){
      std::cerr << "error creating the socket" << std::endl;
      return -1;        
      }
      // to avoid error 'Address already in Use'
      int optval = 1;
      setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval));         

      if( -1==bind( sd, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen ) ){
      printf("%m\n");
      std::cerr << "error binding" << std::endl;
      return -1;
      }

      while(true){

           std::cout << "listen" << std::endl;
           if( -1== listen(sd, MAX_BACKLOG ) ){
               std::cerr << "listen didn't work" << std::endl;
               return -1;
           }

           std::cout << "accept" << std::endl;
           sockaddr peer;
              socklen_t addr_size; 
           int pfd = accept( sd, &peer ,&addr_size );
           if( pfd == -1 ){
               std::cerr << "error calling accept()" << std::endl;
               return -1;
           }
           epoll_event ev;
           ev.data.fd = pfd;
           ev.events =  EPOLLIN;
           std::cout << "adding to epoll list" << std::endl;
           if( -1 == epoll_ctl( epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, pfd, &ev ) ){
               printf("epoll_ctl error %m\n");
               return -1;
           }

      }

 }
 // end of server.cpp



 // client.cpp
     #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <cstdio>
 extern "C"{
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <netdb.h>
 }

 int main(){

      const char* servername = "localhost";
      const char* serverport = "59000";

      struct addrinfo server_address;
      memset( &server_address, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo) );
      server_address.ai_family  =  AF_INET;
      server_address.ai_socktype =  SOCK_STREAM;
      server_address.ai_protocol  =  0; // any protocol
      server_address.ai_flags    =  0;

      struct addrinfo * result, * rp;

      int res = getaddrinfo( servername, serverport, &server_address, &result );
      if( -1 == res ){
         std::cout << "I cannot getaddress " << servername << std::endl;
         return -1;
      }

      int fd = socket( server_address.ai_family
                , server_address.ai_socktype
                , server_address.ai_protocol );
      if( -1 == fd ){
      printf("I cannot open a socket %m\n");
            return -1;
      } 

     for( rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next ){
         std::cout << "************" << std::endl;
        if( -1 == connect( fd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen ) ){
             close(fd);
         }else{
         std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
         break;
       }
     }
     if( rp == NULL ){
         std::cerr << "I couldn't connect server " << servername << std::endl;
     }
     while(true){
         sleep(2);
         pid_t me = getpid();
         char buf[64];
         bzero( buf,sizeof(buf));
         sprintf( buf,"%ld",me );
         write(fd,buf,sizeof(buf));
         printf("%s\n",buf);
      }
 }
 // end of client.cpp
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A client disconnection is signalled by an EOF condition on the file descriptor. The system considers EOF to be a state in which the file descriptor is 'readable'. But, of course, the EOF condition cannot be read. This is the source of your looping. `epoll` is acting like the file descriptor for the disconnected client is **always** readable. You can detect that you have an EOF condition by checking when `read` returns 0 bytes read.

The only way to deal with an EOF condition is to `close` the file descriptor in some way. Depending on exactly how the flow of things go, this could be with `shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RD)`, `shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RDWR)` or `close(sockfd);`.

Unless you know that you need the [`shutdown(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) call for whatever reason, I would recommend you use `close`. Of course, you should remember to tell `epoll` that the file descriptor is no longer of interest before you `close`. I'm not sure what will happen if you don't, but one possibility is that `epoll` will error. Another is that `epoll` will mysteriously begin reporting events for a new file descriptor that has the same numeric value before you add it to the list `epoll` should care about.

Comment: Hi Omnifaruous. Thanks for your response and I ask you the same question I asked Nikolai ( I like both your responses ): in this case is it correct to add a call to epoll_ctl to REMOVE the file descriptor from the epoll list by using  EPOLL_CTL_DEL?

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile: I haven't used epoll too much, so I'm not sure. I would, just because its the clean thing to do and it won't hurt. But the file descriptor should be closed in some form because not doing so is a resource leak.

Comment: No worries! and THanks again for the nice reponse it helped me a lot!

Comment: This is very interesting! Could you please provide some documentation links?

Comment: @Victor - What, specifically are you looking for documentation for?

Comment: @Omnifarious I am curious why EOF comes when the socket is closed remotely

Comment: @Victor - I've done some hunting for this, but I haven't really found anything definitive. I will say that the conceptual model I give to people for a TCP connection is a long stream of ticker tape that moves forwards in fits and starts with a large inscrutable mechanism sitting between the production of the ticker tape and your program. In this model, it's fairly natural to understand the remote side closing the socket as an end to the ticker tape. This way of thinking is common to all the Unix character stream devices/files. I think it's just so obvious to people who know the system...

Comment: @Victor - Also, a TCP connection is actually two strings of ticker tape, one you're producing (with a write call) and another you're consuming (with a read call). That's why `shutdown` exists. It's a way to end just one of the strings. If you close reading when the remote hasn't stopped writing, it will eventually get an error when writing.

Comment: @Omnifarious I understand why it happens conceptually, but I was curious if there is any code in the Kernel, or some documentation that you could point me to. :)

Answer (score 3):

Socket cleanly closed by the other side will become readable and [`read(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html) will return `0`, you have to check for that. As coded now - level-triggered poll - [`epoll_wait(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) returns every time without waiting telling that you still haven't read that end-of-stream.

Alternatively, you can switch to edge-triggered poll (`EPOLLET`) and react to `EPOLLRDHUP` too.

Comment: Hi Nikolai. Thanks a lot for your kind response. Can I ask you 2 more questions? 1. If in this case it returns immediately 0 but the socket is closed would it be good to REMOVE the file descriptor from the epoll_wait list with epoll_ctl with value  EPOLL_CTL_DEL? 2. When I use level-triggered-poll what EPOLLRHUP is meant for? Reading docs I understood that it is detected when a client closes connection but you are saying that this is valid only for the edge-triggered case.

Comment: 1. `close()`-ed socket is removed from kernel poll state automatically, there's no harm removing it with `epoll_ctl` though to make sure you didn't `dup` it somewhere. 2. You can still use `EPOLLRDHUP` in level-triggered mode, but afair you'll need to check for zero-length read anyway.