# How to wait on a error/close event for a socket with asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I am using a networking library who provides a wrapper for using its coroutine functions with `asyncio`. When I wrote a test that randomly closes the connection (to see if my program is resilient under bad conditions), I found that it hangs indefinitely.

It seemed like a bug in the wrapper provided by the library I was using, because the program hangs waiting on the callback from either `loop.add_reader()` or `loop.add_writer()`, but then I could not find how to be notified when the socket is closed.

This is a minimal program that shows what is happening with my program:

```
import asyncio
import socket

async def kill_later(c):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    c.close()

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    c = socket.create_connection(('www.google.com', 80))
    c.setblocking(0)

    ev = asyncio.Event()
    loop.add_reader(c, ev.set)

    # Closes the socket after 0.1 ms:
    asyncio.create_task(kill_later(c))

    print("waiting...")

    #### ↓ THIS WAITS FOREVER ↓ ####
    await ev.wait()

asyncio.run(main())
```

My question: how to be notified a socket is closed by the `asyncio` loop?

EDIT: due to popular demand, made the socket non-blocking, but it makes no difference, because `add_reader()` doesn't try to perform any IO on the socket, merely watches for when it is ready.

Comment: Makes no diference being blocking or not, `loop.add_reader()` adds the socket to `epoll`, it doesn't try to read from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test program is flawed. A call to `c.close()` doesn't emulate the socket being closed by the other end, it closes your own file descriptor and makes it inaccessible. You can think of `close(fd)` as breaking the link between the number *fd* and the underlying OS resource. After that reading and polling *fd* becomes meaningless because the number no longer refers to anything. As a result, `epoll()` can't and won't report a closed file descriptor as "readable".

The way to test the condition you want to test is by having the **other end** close the connection. The easiest way to do that is by spawning another process or thread as a mock server. For example:

```
import asyncio, threading, socket, time

def start_mock_server():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('localhost', 10000))
    s.listen(1)
    def serve():
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        time.sleep(1)
        conn.close()
        s.close()
    threading.Thread(target=serve).start()

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    start_mock_server()

    c = socket.create_connection(('localhost', 10000))
    c.setblocking(0)

    ev = asyncio.Event()
    loop.add_reader(c.fileno(), ev.set)

    print("waiting...")
    await ev.wait()
    print("done")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue, at least with your example, is that your socket never receives anything, hence the event is never set. The docs mention in an [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#watch-a-file-descriptor-for-read-events):

> Wait until a file descriptor received some data using the
>   loop.add_reader() method and then close the event loop

In order for your example to work, you'll have to send a request to Google first:

```
c = socket.create_connection(('www.google.com', 80))
c.sendall("GET /\r\n".encode())
```

This will set the event, that you `await` later in your `main` coro.

`epoll` considers a file descriptor ready to read if data becomes available on it or if an EOF is signalled, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563812/4134674).

`add_writer()` does not block in such a situation, because a file descriptor is considered ready to write as long as there is still space available on the input buffer.

Calling `recv()`, as I mentioned in the previous revision of my answer, is not required.

Comment: You are assuming `loop.add_reader()` tries to read from the socket with `recv()` or similar. It does not. Doesn't matter whether it is blocking or not, because it is merely watched via epoll (on Linux) or similar (on other systems), and invokes the callback when socket is ready.

Comment: And I can't control when the socket will be closed. Maybe a firewall closes it just after I send the request, maybe the server closes it, maybe my cable is disconnected. There must be a way my program will not block waiting forever on a socket that is abruptly closed, so it can never be ready for reading again. My problem is not during normal operating conditions, my problem is how to make my network application resilient to network problems.

Comment: I don't assume that `add_reader()` tries to `recv()` from the socket. That would be detrimental. But ready for read is only triggered when data becomes available on the file descriptor or an EOF is signalled. Neither happens in your example. If the connection breaks, an exception will raise and you will see that. For the cases demonstrated in your example, a non-blocking socket can help to recover from a connection that does not become ready for read. You are right, however, that the `c.recv()` in `kill_later` is not necessary, as long as the socket becomes readable at some point.